# How can I make this so it becomes visible when hovered over

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility, hidden

I'm just trying to make a paragraph that becomes visible when I hover over it. In HTML I just have a paragraph inside the body, and I've also tried it in a div in the body.My code in CSS is just

```
p{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}

p:hover p{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you cannot put `<p>` elements inside another `<p>`, that might be the problem. You can use a `<div>` or any of [these](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) as the container.

```
<div><p>paragraph</p></div>

div p {}
div:hover p {}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Strange because I thought I had tried this but I guess not. Thanks!

Comment: great! also be aware, `visibility:hidden;` will keep the space there although it's hidden. you can also use `display: none;` if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with the `opacity` element in css. Do note that there are vendor specific usages with opacity and transition.

```css
   .hover-vis {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out
    }

.hover-vis:hover {
    opacity: 1
    }
```

```html
<p class="hover-vis">I show up when hovered on</p>
<p>I'm normal</p>
```